# AmCharts parseDates unexpected behavior and merges all bars from the chart

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I'm using AmCharts to display a chart. It's a floating bar chart displaying sent out surveys to a user. The bars are representing the `openFrom` to `openUntil` time, the time window a user has to submit the survey. They're listed in a timeline. I want AmCharts to understand the x-axis has dates as datatype so I can leverage the date functions (relative spacing, showing change of year bold, scrolling in time etc)

The following data is used to plot the chart as seen in the screenshots:

```
[{
    "survey":"Survey DEF",
    "openFrom":"05-04-2016",
    "openUntil":"04-05-2016",
    "status":"Nog niet geopend.", // translates to Not opened yet
    "color":"#ededed"
 },{
    "survey":"Survey DEF",
    "openFrom":"01-01-2016",
    "openUntil":"31-01-2016",
    "status":"Nog niet geopend.",
    "color":"#ededed"
 },{
    "survey":"Survey GHI",
    "openFrom":"06-12-2015",
    "openUntil":"31-12-2015",
    "status":"Ingestuurd op 07-12-2015", // Translates to Submitted at 07-12-2015
    "color":"#27ae60"
 },{
    "survey":"Survey ABC",
    "openFrom":"01-12-2015",
    "openUntil":"15-12-2015",
    "status":"Geopend, nog geen reactie.", // Translates to Opened, not submitted yet
    "color":"#e67e22"
 },{
    "survey":"Survey GHI",
    "openFrom":"31-01-2015",
    "openUntil":"05-05-2015",
    "status":"Geen reactie ontvangen", // Translates to Not submitted
    "color":"#c0392b"
}]
```

Using this code:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart('chart-container', {
    'type': 'serial',
    'dataLoader': {
       'url': urlToJSONFetchScript
    },
    'language': 'nl',
    'categoryAxis': {
        'position': 'right',
        'axisAlpha': 0.2,
        'gridAlpha': 0.05
    },
    'valueAxes': [{
        'type': 'date',
        'minimumDate': '31-01-2015',
        'maximumDate': '04-05-2016',
        'axisAlpha': 0.2,
        'gridAlpha': 0.05
    }],
    'categoryField': 'survey',
    'graphs': [{
        'balloonText': '<div style="text-align: left"><strong>[[survey]]</strong><small><br/>[[openFrom]] - [[openUntil]]<br/>[[status]]</small></div>',
        'type': 'column',
        'dateFormat': 'DD-MM-YYYY',
        'openField': 'openFrom',
        'valueField': 'openUntil',
        'colorField': 'color',
        'lineColorField': 'color',
        'fillAlphas': 0.65,
        'lineAlpha': 0.95
    }],
    'rotate': true,
    'dataDateFormat': 'DD-MM-YYYY'
});
```

It get's me this chart:
[image]

This all looks good, but I'd like to use parseDates zo the x-axis doesn't have string-labels, but relatively spreads the dates and also displaying year changes. When I add `'parseDates': true` to `categoryAxis` the chart rotates and is rendered all wrong. I've been searching in the [API documentation](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts) for a while but I can't find any solution. What am I missing?

Result with parseDates set to true in categoryAxis options:
[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "relatively spreads the dates and also displaying year changes"? It currently is using natural time scale. However it omits some of the month labels. Do you mean you want to display all months and year start bolded labels?

Comment: I mean it as explained in this article: http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/time-series-chart-the-great-advantages-of-parsing-dates/. At this moment it parses the labels `Survey ..` as date, but the X-axis should be as a date type, not string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the issue is that you need to display all month labels, as well as the year on January.

For this, you will need to set `boldPeriodBeginning: true` as well as `markPeriodChange: true` to display year instead of January label.

To make the chart display all months, you'll also need to disable auto grid by setting `autoGridCount: false`, as well as set `gridCount` to some larger number, say 25.

Please note that this is all for **Value Axis**. Enabling parsing of dates for category axis does not make a lot of sense, since you have arbitrary categories, 
like "Survey DEF".

```
'valueAxes': [ {
  'type': 'date',
  'minimumDate': '31-01-2015',
  'maximumDate': '04-05-2016',
  'autoGridCount': false,
  'gridCount': 25,
  'boldPeriodBeginning': true,
  'markPeriodChange': true,
  'axisAlpha': 0.2,
  'gridAlpha': 0.05
} ]
```

Here's the [live chart](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/5d98a2999bc9f9e01ff69c00b22f768a) with the above changes.

[image]

---

As of V3.18 of JavaScript Charts, it is also possible to make the value axis scrollable. To enable that, use [`valueScrollbar`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#valueScrollbar) property of the chart. I.e.:

```
"valueScrollbar": {
  "oppositeAxis": false,
  "offset": 50,
  "scrollbarHeight": 10
}
```

It's an instance of [ChartScrollbar](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ChartScrollbar), so you can use any properties available in this class.

[image]

Comment: Second time you've helped me out today! Thanks a bunch! I was kinda focussing on the `parseDates` option because of the tutorial I mentioned. I would +10 if I could.. Have a nice day!

Comment: By the way, can I add a horizontal scrollbar to the chart? When defining `chartScrollbar` it gets displayed vertically.

Comment: Not yet. But tomorrow we're releasing a new version V3.18 which will support value axis scrollbars. I'll update my answer with how you can implement it, when the new version is available. Cool?

Comment: Awesome! Found out later you're one of the owners. Great work!

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: One more question, but I think it isn;t supported (yet). Can I set an "initial range". For example the timeline min and max are 01-01-2014 and 01-01-2018. I'd like to initial zoom into today - 6 months and today + 12 months. I've tried using the minimum and maximum, but they don't seem to have an effect since the docs tell an integer is expected but I'm providing a date.

Comment: For date-based value axis use `minimumDate` and `maximumDate` instead. http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#minimumDate

Comment: I'm using the minimumDate and maximumDate, that's working fine. But I'm trying to set a "zoom window" in the scrollbar for a part of the range to be shown.

Comment: Not sure I understand what "zoom window" is. Isn't that just start and end dates? Precisely what you set with minimumDate/maximumDate.

Comment: Maybe I'm overcomplicating my way of saying. Lets say the minimumDate is 2014-01-01 and maximumDate is 2018-01-01. I want to set the range/slider for the scrollbar to display (from today) - 6 months and + 12 months, so from 2015-06-14 to 2016-12-14. In other words, I would like to provide values for the position of the dragIcons. Can this be done?

Comment: Well, you'll need to calculate the dates for `minimuDate` and `maximumDate` then. I.e. `var minimumDate = new Date(); maximumDate = new Date( minimumDate ); maximumDate.setFullYear( minimumDate.getFullYear() + 1 );`